# Windows file explorer keeps asking to open a file instead of going to address

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Win 10 x64

Problem:

I open Windows file explorer and enter the folder destintion in the address bar. It then highights the inputted address, deletes it & restores the current destination & pops up the "Which program to you want to open this file with" dialogue. This pop up also appears on booting the computer.

[image]

I can navigate using the icons only or using a cmd terminal

Comment: Does it also happen if you don't have Quick access open? Eg, press This PC first, then type in the addressbar? Also, what exactly do you type in the addressbar? For example does `C:\` work?

Comment: @LPChip it happens when I paste in `C:\Users\Nic Bwts\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages` it doesn't matter where I start from. `C:` does work

Comment: Is it possible you are pasting a space or is there also a file called site-packages in the Python38 folder, and it tries to open that file rather than navigating to the folder?

Comment: Its a folder, it turns out that in the pasted one the dash in `site‑packages` and the dash in the manually typed `site-packages` are different. The latter works btw. Have you seen this kind of thing before?

Comment: Yes I have. Word processors often change a - to a different - as part of typography if you type it manually, or you paste it, and then press space.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of troubleshooting, it seemed this happened to a specific location that was pasted in. The location does not actually exist because the - sign was changed.

Explorer then treats this as a file and asks how you want to open this instead.